# Does the material of the slits affect the pattern of the electrons in the double-slit experiment?

Tags: double-slit-experiment, material-science

The question comes from thinking about the way how electrons act on the slits. Do material of the slits affect electrons motion? Assume the radius or length of the slits are set in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Does the material affect the [double slit experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment)?  **No, but with some important conditions.**

The double slit experiment is designed to measure the diffraction interference pattern of the wave-nature of matter like photons and electrons.  The material used to make the slits is meant to either completely block the incident particles where there isn't a slit or let them pass completely through where there is a slit.  The boundary between the material and the slit is supposed to be sharp.  That's why the barriers **S1** and **S2** don't need labels:

[image: double slit diagram]

If you chose a material that didn't have these properties (or if you made the barrier so thin it could be tunneled through) you wouldn't really have the double slit experiment anymore.

So, given an appropriate choice of material, the experimental results don't change from material to material.  The experiment is based on the geometry of the slits and the wavelength of the incident particles and not the particle-material interaction.

Comment: I had checked your answer, but having thought further on this, I think that the real experiment is a solution of the quantum mechanical equation with boundaries for the  electron  the two slits, and in this case the conductivity for example should play a role at some level. It should not just be geometry if one could solve exactly.

Answer (score 1):

"The material of the slits" (it would be more correct to say "the material of the screen with slits", as there is no material in the slits) definitely "affects electron's motion". For example, "In the course of our previous qualitative study an unexpected broadening of the diffraction peaks was observed.27 We show that the broadening of the diffraction
peaks is affected by the type and thickness of metallic coating" (http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1060&context=mrsecfacpubs ). The reason is the "image charges" in the screen with which electrons interact depend on the electric properties of the screen.