# Flaws of Double Slit Experiment?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, double-slit-experiment

The double slit experiment usually use knife blades for the slit.
But knife blades are made of metal and they are highly reflective for light rays.
This means the incident light should reflect off the tip of the blade and create unnecessary interference.

As shown in the image below:

[image]

Has this effect been properly prevented by using a non-reflective surface such as "Vantablack" for the slit?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantablack

Is the current double slit experiment flawed?
Or do they have a way to prevent this effect?

Comment: related http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78707/

Comment: @annav The significant difference is. Reflection vs Penetration.

Comment: You can do it with razor blades as well as with organic material on stretched foil. But that an interaction between the light and the edges takes place is without doubt.

Comment: In that scenario I'd say there are two variables to consider: the width of the edges and the divergence of the incoming light. If the pattern is created from reflection the way you depicted, then the width of the edges and divergence of the light would effect the intensity of peripheral fringes of the pattern. This hasn't been observed (technically the divergence of the light does come into play in Fresnel diffraction but my point is that your scenario would imply much more sensitivity to the divergence of the light).

Comment: Also, just in general, a laser sends light that is very close to being parallel rays (or equivalently as a plane wave), and almost all renditions of the double-slit experiment with light are done with a laser. (As someone pointed out, technically the material does play a role, because without the material you wouldn't have any slits! But the point is that the interactions aren't explainable with classical ray optics.)

Comment: @MaximalIdeal It is true that laser light is parallel. However, if the knife blade is rounded, then a parallel light ray hitting the rounded knife blade will deflect the light into the slit and cause the 'unnecessary interference'.

Answer (score 2):

In the classical electrodynamics [doubles slits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_interference_experiment) experiment , reflection and refraction of light at the edges hit play a role in creating the pattern. If the light goes through without interacting with the slits there is no interference. That is why the distance between the slits and the size of the slits  with respect to the wavelength under study is important. The slit has to be small enough so that it becomes a point source, the refracting part of the wave off the straight incoming path giving rise to interference.

The same is true for the quantum mechanical view of photons, for light, and electrons, where they have a quantum mechanical probability distribution impinging on the two slits, solved by the boundary value problem " particle falling on two slits of given width and separation" , which will give a wavefunction, which complex conjugate squared gives the interference pattern, even [one photon at a time](http://tps://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/).

[image: snglephotdblslit]

> Single-photon camera recording of photons from a double slit illuminated by very weak laser light. Left to right: single frame, superposition of 200, 1’000, and 500’000 frames.

What you call "unnecessary interference" is a necessary part of the explanation of the interference both classically and quantum mechanically. [This answer for electrons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78707/does-the-material-of-the-slits-affect-the-pattern-of-the-electrons-in-the-double) is relevant to the discussion.

Comment: This is wrong. The slits can be quite wide, 10 microns in optics for example. That is much more than the wavelength, so such a slit is not a point source.

Comment: @Pieter please see this definition of point source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_source#Light

Comment: Well, whatever wikipedia says. You argue that the edges are important. That is wrong. Of course in some sense, it is the electrons in the two opaque halfplanes that cause the diffraction pattern. But not "reflection and refraction of light at the edges hit".

Comment: I agree with @Pieter. For a typical slit width, only a tiny fraction of the light interacts with the slit edges which would typically lead to very dim interference patterns. Huygens principle applied to the plane wavefront passing through the slit accounts for the light that creates the pattern.

Comment: For the photon the slit edges and distance  are what define the wavefunction andthus the probability of ending at an (x,y) point, no matter where it ends up in the classical patter, so I will not edit, since the classical is the superposition of the quantum. I will  put in the single photon once more.

Answer (score 2):

Of course this has been done: scratches on a sooted glass plate. It is the standard set-up in the course lab, for example:
https://www.pasco.com/products/lab-apparatus/light-and-optics/diffraction/os-8453

The slits can be made by a photographic process. Or by printing in a laser printer, using toner on a transparency: Van Hook, [Inquiry with Laser Printer Diffraction Gratings](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.2768688), The Physics Teacher **45**, 340 (2007).